# What's the name of a jQuery plugin acting like a slideshow

Tags: jquery, plugins, slideshow

I want, in my website, to present my employees, and i want to do it like a slideshow or similar using jQuery.

You know, example i have 6 emplpoyees photo, and when i hover them, there is a little presentation with a bigger photo of them.

I completely lost the name of the plugin i found months ago

(if you know others jquery plugin who do the same or similar, feel free to speak ;D )

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were probably thinking of [the cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/), but there are also [tons more](http://blueprintds.com/2009/01/20/top-14-jquery-photo-slideshow-gallery-plugins/) :D

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned already, there are *tons*. I personally use [jQuery Scrollable](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable). Even though it's more of a general-purpose scrolling UI widget, the demo shows how it can be used for slideshows or image galleries. And it would be simple to trigger selection using hover.

If you're going to create a slide-show-type gallery, you usually use 2 main UI components: 1.) a thumbnail/slides menu and 2.) the actual display box that shows your slides.

Scrollable obviously focuses on #1 and leaves the actual slide display up to you to implement. But the nice thing about it is that you can easily create a nice linear thumbnail menu that you can scroll through by mouse click, mouse position, or mouse-wheel movement.

Displaying the selected slide should be easy enough to implement on your own. jQuery even comes with a bunch of fancy animations that you can use for your slide transitions.